# How can I pass Node Info to Contact Page in Drupal 7?

Tags: module, drupal-7, drupal-modules, contact-form

I'm using Drupal 7, and I'm wondering if I can do a booking contact form page like this:

https://www.kiwicollection.com/hotel-detail/casa-grande-hotel-resort-spa

Where on this example, if you click on "group booking" it takes you to:

https://www.kiwicollection.com/booking/request/PR000196

So a standard booking request contact page but it knows which hotel you clicked the request from, so the left column is filled with info on that hotel.

Can someone point me in the direction of a module that would help accomplish this? I'd need to be on a resort/hotel page, click "book now", and get taken to the common Contact Us page, but with pre-filled out info from the Resort/Hotel that the user was on, e.g. image/title/description/price etc, in a summary section of the contact page. (Obviously I wouldn't want to make a separate contact page/webform for each hotel, so it needs to just pull the dynamic info based on which Resort they were on when they clicked "Book now!"

TIA!

Comment: You can load a node id  on the hotel detail page and on the group booking link, you can insert the nid/wherever and  on on the form page you can load the node info with the nid passed on the url.

Comment: I understand the plan and that should work, but how do I use the nid on the /contact page's end, to display the proper information? Say I needed to load the field_image, field_title, and field_description of nid=829... can you give any more details on how to pull those pieces just from the nid in the url?

Comment: get the node id and you can load the whole node by `$node = node_load('nid');` and you can `dpm($node); ` or `var_dump($node);` and pick whichever fields you need.